# Summation closed form.

Tags: summation, closed-form

I have tried to figure out how to get the close form of:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^22^{n-k}.$$

I tried to write down each number of the summation but couldn't find any thing to do with that..

can please someone explain to me how to do it? thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why do you think there is one?

Comment: Factor $2^n$. Now you have this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833480/how-could-i-find-the-partial-sum-of-this-function

Comment: @DonAntonio, [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+0+to+n+of+k^2*n^%28n-k%29) yields a closed form.

Comment: @recursiverecursion, your link sent me to the sum of the first $\;n\;$ natural numbers, nothing to do with the present case...

Comment: @DonAntonio, are you sure? Click it again.

Comment: Oh @recursiverecursion, now it is a new link...but still not the sum we have in the OP: here, it is a constant $\;2^{n-k}\;$ in the sum, there in WA it is $\;n^{n-k}\;$ ...

Comment: Rewrite it as $2^n\sum_{k=0}^n k^22^{-k}$ and then work out what $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 z^k$ is.

Comment: @DonAntonio, [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+0+to+n+of+k^2*2^%28n-k%29) is the closed form according to WA.

Comment: Oh, finally @recursiverecursion: **that** indeed is the formula . :)

Answer (score 2):

We can solve it by convolution of generating functions:

\begin{align*}
  A(x) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} k^2\, x^k = \frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3} \\
  B(x) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} 2^k\, x^k = \frac{1}{1-2\, x} \\
  A(x)\cdot B(x) &= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{k= 0}^n k^2\, 2^{n-k} \right) x^n = \frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3(1-2\, x)}
\end{align*}
Then we can extract $[x^n]$ by doing partial fractions:
\begin{align*}
  A(x)\cdot B(x) &= \frac{6}{1-2 \, x } - \frac{2}{{\left(1-x\right)}^{3}} - \frac{1}{{\left( 1-x\right)}^{2}} -\frac{3}{1-x} 
\end{align*}

Hence,
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k= 0}^n k^2\, 2^{n-k} &= 6\cdot 2^n - 2\, \binom{n+2}{2} - \binom{n+1}{1} - 3 \\
  &= 6\cdot 2^n - n^2 - 4\, n - 6
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it took a while, but I've been able to derive the formula. Let us define $f(n)$ to be the sum in question. Now we have that $f(n+1) = 2f(n) + (n+1)^2$, the $(n+1)^2$ coming from the last term, and the doubling of $f(n)$ being a result of raising the exponent on the $2$ by a factor of $1$ for each term. Now we have a recurrence relation, which is $f(0) = 0, f(n+1) = 2f(n) + (n+1)^2$.

Substituting $n$ for $n+1$ yields $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + n^2$, and dividing both sides by $2^n$ gives us $$\frac{f(n)}{2^n} = \frac{f(n-1)}{2^{n-1}} + \frac{n^2}{2^n}.$$

Now we define another function $g(n)$ to be $f(n)/2^n$, so we have $$g(n) = g(n-1) + \frac{n^2}{2^n}$$
$$\implies g(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{k^2}{2^k}.$$

It is not hard to work out the closed form of $g(n)$, which is $2^{-n}[6(2^n)-n^2-4n-6]$. Now we recall that $g(n) := f(n)/2^n$, and of course multiplying $g(n)$ by $2^n$ yields $6(2^n)-n^2-4n-6$, which is indeed the closed form of your summation. Many thanks to Ayman Hourieh, who responded to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835346/finding-the-explicit-function-of-a-recursive-sequence/835354?noredirect=1#comment1724130_835354).